# Solution of equation $ x^2\equiv 1 \pmod{784}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

How to solve the equation $ x^2\equiv 1 \pmod{784}$ ?

#### Context

I know the Chinese Remainder theorem, but have no idea how to begin. Could you give me any clue? The only thing that I would like to is learn and understand this subject.

It is very important to me see example solved by person who is experienced.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you familiar with the Chinese Remainder theorem?

Comment: Hint: The congruence $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{49}$ has $2$ solutions, and the congruence $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{16}$ has $4$.

Comment: Yes, I know this theorem. I have no idea how to begin. Could you give me any clue ? The only thing that I would like to is learn and understand this subject.

Answer (score 1):

This breaks down into
$$x^2\equiv 1\pmod{49},$$
that is equivalent to $x\equiv\pm 1\pmod{49}$ since $(\mathbb{Z}/49\mathbb{Z})^*$ is a cyclic group, and into:
$$x^2\equiv 1\pmod{16}$$
whose solutions are $x\equiv \pm 1,\pm 7\pmod{16}$.

Comment: Ok, as for $x^2\equiv 1 (\mod 16)$  - I see that your solution is good. But two very important for me questions: (1) From what do you know that ${1, -1, -7, 7}$ are $only$ solutions ? (2) What was your $way$ to find these solution ?

Comment: It comes from the fact that $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^*$ (for n\geq 2) is not a cyclic group, but its elements can all be written as $\pm 5^k$. $5$ generates half of the group, to be clear, and the other elements are just the opposite.

Comment: Since the order of $5$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z})^*$ is $4$, the solution of $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{16}$ are given by $x\equiv 5^0,5^2,-5^0,-5^2\pmod{16}$.

Comment: Ok, but I don't know group theory currently. Could you try to explain it without groups ?

Comment: Then, just try to found the solutions of $(x-1)(x+1)\equiv 0\pmod{16}$. Obviously $x\equiv \pm 1\pmod{16}$ gives two solutions, but we get a solution even if $(x-1)$ is even and $(x+1)$ is a multiple of eight, or the opposite, hence $x\equiv\pm 7\mod{16}$. The hardest part is now to prove without using anything advanced that a quadratic equation $\pmod{16}$ may have four roots *at most*.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,m,n\,$ are coprime then, by CRT, solving a polynomial $\,f(x)\equiv \,$ mod $\,mn\,$ is equivalent to solving $\,f(x)\equiv 0\,$ mod $\,m\,$ and mod $\,n.\,$ By CRT, each combination of a root $\,r_i\,$ mod $\,n\,$ and a root $\,s_j\,$ mod $\,n\,$ corresponds to a unique root $\,t_{ij}\,$ mod $\,mn\,$ i.e.

$$\begin{eqnarray} f(x)\equiv 0\pmod{mn}&\overset{\rm CRT}\iff& \begin{array}{}f(x)\equiv 0\pmod m\\f(x)\equiv 0\pmod n\end{array} \\ 
&\iff&  \begin{array}{}x\equiv r_1,\ldots,r_k\pmod m\phantom{I^{I^{I^I}}}\\x\equiv s_1,\ldots,s_\ell\pmod n\end{array}\\ 
&\iff& \left\{ \begin{array}{}x\equiv r_i\pmod m\\x\equiv s_j\pmod n\end{array} \right\}_{\begin{array}{}1\le i\le k\\ 1\le j\le\ell\end{array}}^{\phantom{I^{I^{I^I}}}}\\
&\overset{\rm CRT}\iff& \left\{ x\equiv t_{i j}\!\!\pmod{mn} \right\}_{\begin{array}{}1\le i\le k\\ 1\le j\le\ell\end{array}}\\
\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$

Answer (score 0):

784 = 16*49.  Solve x²=1 in both, and use the remainder therom.

You end up with (1,7,9,15)(1,48), which gives 1; 295, 393; 687., and 784 less these.